# Checking JBOSS version from a webapp URL

Tags: linux, curl

I have a web application URL and I am interested to know which JBOSS version it is running behind. How can I check that? Is it possible to check with `curl`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no.

If the JBoss instance is configured poorly, a provoked error message might leak the version number. This can - of course - be done using `curl`, as well as with any other means to send invalid requests to the application in question.